# Isn't it possible to use the full width of the watch's screen? Always get a 1 point border

Tags: ios, watchkit

Isn't it possible to use the full width of the screen e.g. for a Group or an ImageView?

I always see a one point border on both sides when I set the width "relative to container".

I don't understand why, as the clock has a black frame nonetheless.
So it seems to make no sense to add another virtual border that steals canvas from the already small enough screen.

Any way to surround this, or is it just the way we have to use it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe setting the margin and/or the padding to 0 will fix it.

The [IOS Dev Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/Layout.html) states though :

> Use the full width of the screen. Because the bezel on Apple Watch adds visual padding around your content, you do not need to include margins between the screen edge and your content. (Note that this padding is not present in iOS Simulator.)

Comment: Thanks. For those who are looking for the solution: Select the ViewController (not the UI element inside) and change Insets in the Inspector from "Default" to "Custom". You will see that there is a default of 1 for left and right. Changing them to 0 will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Spacing and insets has nothing to do with that, it only affects the objects inside the group and seems that you only have 1 group with blue background.

Look this example: 2 groups inside a parent group.

Changing spacing to 5 points, it separates the within groups 5points. (It doesnt change the parent group size). 
[image]
Changing top,left and right to 10 points only change the inner groups size and position, the parent width is the same. 
[image]

If your group with blue background has "relative to container" width, my thoughts is that you are using the maximum width. I currently have the same gap border in my applewatch app. 
[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. Already thought that it would be that way.
Still don't get the reason for that. It definitely is not a border of the simulator. If you measure the pixels you will see, that the colored region is 2 points smaller than the known display sizes of the watch models.

Comment: Oh I was wrong and @TheCoolFrood was correct.
You can set the Insets of a ViewController to 0, while the default is 1